# ios swift display the images according to all the iOS devices and orientations programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, scaling

I am trying to design the main menu page for a pizza shop. 
No, I have  "pizza" and "creams & desserts" images respectively -

[image]

[image]

which when in storyboard iPhone 4s, potrait mode (scale to fill) look like -

[image]

[image]

which may still look descent, but when scaled to iPhone 11 , landscape  mode look like -

[image]

[image]

Which do not at all look descent.

Now,my first question is how should I display the images according to all the iOS devices and orientations programmatically ?

The full menu image  screenshot  iPhone 4s, potrait mode,  is -

[image]

Also, to be noted here is that clicking on respective images will lead to respective Viewcontrollers. I could have used buttons here but, that (according to me), does not look stylish. So, my second question is how to should I scale the  full menu page according to  fit all the devices and orientations(maybe programmatically).

I know about auto layouts. I was just wondering whether I can I use different orientations and devices. Can it be done through switch cases or enums ? Also, I need to connect them to segue(don't worry. I have the swipe code). Is it possible ?

Comment: Use UICollectionView and adjust size of each item in sizeForItemAtIndexPath Delegate method. And for image, you have to give .aspectFit or .aspectFill according to your requirement. .scaleToFill won't work for dynamic images.

Comment: Use Adaptive Layouts : https://www.raywenderlich.com/1343912-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-12-getting-started

Comment: who gave negative marks. I discussed my problem and again negative marks. please remove it, really frustrates.

Comment: guys I know about auto layouts. I was just wondering whether I  can I  use different orientations and devices. Can it be done through switch cases or enums ? Also, I  need to connect them to segue(don't worry. I have the swipe code). Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Auto Layout, just filling or fitting your image is not enough if you want to have good User Interface.

You can tons of youtube videos or articles about Auto Layout and Constraints specifically, using size classes, where you have specific cases of your device size.

Here's one example by Sean allen - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_0_XQEfrGQ